# AWS CloudWatch: EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I just followed these instructions ([Link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/QuickStartEC2Instance.html])) to get AWS CloudWatch installed on my EC2 instance.

1. I updated my repositories: sudo yum update -y
2. I installed the awslogs package: sudo yum install -y awslogs
3. I edited the /etc/awslogs/awscli.conf, confirming that my AZ is us-west-2b on the EC2 page
4. I left the default condiguration of the /etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf file as is, confirming that the default path indeed has logs being written to it
5. I checked the /var/log/awslogs.log file and it is repeatedly showing the error:
   EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://logs.us-west-2b.amazonaws.com/"

   - I do not see any newly created log group and log stream in the CloudWatch console as expected. What am I missing here?

Should I be pointing at some other endpoint other than https://logs.us-west-2b.amazonaws.com/ ? If so, where is that configured?

Thanks in advance,

Graham

Comment: Under IAM >> users >> your user >> policies: did you update your policy to allow creation of the group/stream?

Comment: @vath I did - this user has full admin access in my sandbox acct:

{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: I had some issues getting the log group and log stream created so I went into cloud watch console and manually created a new group and stream.  Then in IAM >> Users >> (my user name) >> "Permissions" tab >>  [Attach Policy]: I added "AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs" permission to my user.  I've been able to write logs to that stream in region US_WEST_2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The awscli.conf expects the region and not the AZ.

Specify the region as us-west-2.

Here is the documentation from the reference page

```html
Edit the /etc/awslogs/awscli.conf file and in the [default] section, specify the region where you want to view log data and add your credentials.

region = us-east-1
aws_access_key_id = <YOUR ACCESS KEY>
aws_secret_access_key = <YOUR SECRET KEY>
```

The error 
`EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://logs.us-west-2b.amazonaws.com/"`
could be attributed to wrong specification of region.

The correct endpoint for the cloudwatch logs service in US-WEST-2 is 
`logs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`.

Please refer to the following documentation for aws service endpoints
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#cwl_region

Comment: This was the issue, thanks for the help here, much appreciated