# Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://logs.us-east-1.xxxxx"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a strange issue here and it's driving me nuts.

I have an agent setup on the another application that works smoothly. However, running same gives the error below.

The application with the issue has Route53 integrated with the url like "name.xxbg3wy.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com " while the other application that works smoothly has the url "name.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com"

Is there anything that I'm missing out on here? Could it be that the endpoint-url has to be set somewhere in the config file? The region is "us-east-1" and I've confirmed severally from the config file.

```
2017-07-17 19:20:54,998 - cwlogs.threads - ERROR - 28422 - Thread-11 -   
Exception caught in <EventBatchPublisher(Thread-11, started daemon  
140656144017152)>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/awslogs/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/cwlogs/threads.py", line 58, in run
 self._run()
 File "/var/awslogs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cwlogs/push.py", 
 line 1402, in _run
    self._publish_event_batch()
  File "/var/awslogs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cwlogs/push.py",       
line 1209, in _publish_event_batch
    self.sequence_token = self._put_log_events(self.event_batch)
  File "/var/awslogs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cwlogs/push.py",   
line 1247, in _put_log_events
    response = self.logs_service.put_log_events(**params)
  File "/var/awslogs/local/lib/python2.7/site-  
 packages/botocore/client.py", line 253, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/awslogs/local/lib/python2.7/site-
 packages/botocore/client.py", line 530, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/var/awslogs/local/lib/python2.7/site-
 packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 141, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/var/awslogs/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 170, in _send_request
    success_response, exception):

 EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: 
"https://logs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"

2017-07-17 19:21:55,927 - cwlogs.push.reader - INFO - 28422 - Thread-12 
- Reader is leaving as requested...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your **Security Group** policies? Looks like you might need to whitelist certain ports.

Try for "**All traffic'** first and see of its connects.

You could use, **telnet** service to check the connectivity to ports from your host.

Comment: Thanks @Vineeth, I did that now and still get the endpoint connection error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37493873/aws-cloudwatch-endpointconnectionerror-could-not-connect-to-the-endpoint-url

Does this help?